# javascript onclick event not working in Chrome with SQL driven data

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-chrome

```
<select id='city' name='city' > 
<?php
$dbcon = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($db_name,$dbcon) or die( "Unable to select database");
$city_query = "SELECT city,county FROM citycatalog order by city asc";
$city_res = mysql_query($city_query);
$city_num = mysql_num_rows($city_res);
$i=0;
while($i < $city_num){
$city_val = mysql_result($city_res,$i,'city');
$county_val = mysql_result($city_res,$i,'county');
echo "<option value=\"$city_val\" onClick=\"document.getElementById('county').value = '$county_val'\" >$city_val</option>";
$i++;
};
?>
</select>
<input type="text" id='county' name='county' />
```

This code does fire up very fine in IE and FF, but not in Chrome and Safari.
I have no idea how to solve this.
I have tried the alternative with onChange event on the select tag, but, the variables are after the select tag and the SQL does not bring any data to the event. 
Please advise a stacked designer.
Thank you!

Comment: Hi, can you include the actual html output generated by php in your question? Makes copy&paste easier and will get you help quicker.

Comment: What type of element is `#distr`?

Comment: here is the outputted code in Chrome
    <select id='city' name='city' style="width:300px; text-align:left;" > 
    <option value="1 DECEMBRIE-IF" onClick="document.getElementById('county').value = 'ZONA 2'" >1 DECEMBRIE-IF</option>
    <option value="23 AUGUST-CT" onClick="document.getElementById('county').value = 'CONSTANTA'" >23 AUGUST-CT</option>
    <option value="ABRUD-AB" onClick="document.getElementById('county').value = 'ALBA'" >ABRUD-AB</option>
 ...
    </select>
    <input type="text" id='county' name='county' />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onclick` is not supported for `option`s. You should use `onchange` of the `select`. The value can be stored in an attribute like `data-county` (`data-` attributes can be used to store data on an element):

```
<select id='city' name='city' onchange="document.getElementById('county').value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-county');"> 
<?php
$dbcon = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($db_name,$dbcon) or die( "Unable to select database");
$city_query = "SELECT city,county FROM citycatalog order by city asc";
$city_res = mysql_query($city_query);
$city_num = mysql_num_rows($city_res);
$i=0;
while($i < $city_num){
$city_val = mysql_result($city_res,$i,'city');
$county_val = mysql_result($city_res,$i,'county');
echo "<option value=\"$city_val\" data-county=\"$county_val\" >$city_val</option>";
$i++;
};
?>
</select>
<input type="text" id='county' name='county' />
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, only that the event should be onChange not onSelect. Only onChange did the trick.
Thanks again.